# Find Transformation Matrix for Vectors of Functions, and Restrict Results of Solve Function

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have two vectors `v,w` which have a rather simple linear transformation `A.v=w`. My goal is to obtain `A`.

Take the following example `v={foo[a],foo[b]}` and `w={foo[a]+foo[b],foo[a]-foo[b]}`. Now my attempt to find a linear transformation is

```
Solve[Table[A[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}].v == w,Flatten@Table[A[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]]
```

i.e. I multiply `v` with the 2x2 matrix A in the form of `Table[A[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}` from the left hand side and solve the equality with `w` for all entries `A[i_,j_]`.

The result I would hope for, is

```
{{A[1,1] -> 1, A[1,1] -> 1, A[1,1] -> 1, A[1,1] -> -1}}
```

Instead, I get

```
{{A[1, 2] -> -((A[1, 1] foo[a])/foo[b]) - (-foo[a] - foo[b])/foo[b], A[2, 2] -> -((A[2, 1] foo[a])/foo[b]) - (-foo[a] + foo[b])/foo[b]}}
```

which of course is a correct result, but I want my expressions `A[i_,j_]` to be independent of `foo[x_]`. My question therefore is:

**How do I tell Solve to make the solutions independent of `foo[x_]`?**

I have already tried to define a domain `dom` in `Solve[expr,vars,dom]`, but e.g. `Complexes` does not work, even though

```
In[253]:= MemberQ[Complexes, foo[a]]
Out[253]= False
```

I expect there to be an easier way to find linear transformations in general, but I would like to have this particular issue solved nevertheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your symbolic case, try

```
D[w, {v, 1}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, -1}}

Comment: Thank you very much! This indeed also works for my more complicated problem. I wouldn't have considered `D[]` for this.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had to wait a little longer. I planned to do it tomorrow. It's done now.

Comment: No problem. You can do that whenever you like. It was just a little reminder.

Comment: It was only because I remembered stackexchange not allowing me to do it this early, but it worked. So thanks again and good bye :)